# When are the first 'regular' space tourist commercial flights actually due to start?

Tags: transportation, extreme-tourism, space

We've seen promises from "by the year 2000", 2003, floating hotels by 2007, and so on.  Now we have the first cargo ship by a private company ACTUALLY dock with the ISS, hooray! SpaceshipTwo with Virgin Galactic is finally doing test flights.

However, I can't find any info on their webpages or press releases - a couple of times they've said "in the next two years".

What's the earliest PUBLISHED date any current companies have set for a launch for a tourist flight (excluding NASA or Russian flights)?

**edit**

As I said, **excluding NASA or Russian flights**, and really mean 'mass' tourism - available to those who aren't millionaires.

Comment: I suspect even the first true, undisputed *tourism* of space will only be affordable to millionaires (even if the ticket price is miraculously well under the $1M/€1M mark). I think a better criteria needs to be set than "affordable to non-millionaires." Perhaps: *Tickets available to the general public*?

Comment: well Virgin Galactic is selling tickets for far less than that - US$200k.

Comment: If you can afford a US$200k vacation, you're probably a millionaire. :)

Comment: To Space, or to Orbit? (They're different!) Virgin Galatic for example are only getting into space but not with an orbital velocity

Comment: Space.  Although personally I think first flights should include an orbit, I think the definition should involve seeing the blackness of space, and getting some weightlessness in there.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by *space*. Anything above 100 km? Does suborbital count? [Spaceport Sweden](http://www.spaceportsweden.com/) markets aurora flights as *space tourism* even if it stays well within the troposphere, *because it is about space*; by that definition, visiting an astronomical observatory is also space tourism.

Comment: Downvoted? Gotta love no-commenting downvoters. This is a site for all of us, share your thoughts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Virgin Galactic is now saying it will be in 2013 ( http://m.engadget.com/2012/07/15/richard-branson-confirms-virgin-galactics-first-space-tourism-f/ and http://www.virgingalactic.com/news/item/xxx/ ) and $200,000 per person. I have no affiliation; a friend of mine is on the waiting list. As http://www.virgingalactic.com/booking/ explains, your choices are to pay the entire refundable amount up front and be sure of a seat on the first flight (thus becoming one of the first thousand people in space, since about 500 people have been on NASA or Soviet missions and a little over 500 are on this list), or pay $20,000 and join the waiting list.

Comment: Wish I had $200k right about now....

Comment: Looks like that didn't happen :/

Answer (score 5):

### Space tourism has been taking place since 2001

The first real space tourist<sup>1</sup> was [Dennis Tito](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Tito), spending a week on the [ISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station) in mid-2001. The trip cost him about $20 million US and was organized by [Space Adventures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Adventures), who organized a total of [8 trips for 7 tourists (Charles Simonyi went twice)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Adventures) to the ISS between 2001 and 2009. All trips were made aboard [Soyuz-TMA spacecraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz-TMA). The most recent trips cost around $30-$35 million US. The program is currently on hold, but set to resume next year:

> On January 12, 2011, Space Adventures and the Russian Federal Space Agency announced that orbital space tourism would resume in 2013 with the increase of manned Soyuz launches to the ISS from four to five per year.

<sup>1</sup> The term "space tourist" is [disputable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_tourism#Objections_to_.22space_tourist.22_terminology).

Comment: sorry, but as I specifically said, *excluding* NASA or Russian flights :/

Comment: There are no others that have even a year set yet. Virgin Galactic sells "priority seating", but does not specify any date.

Comment: Also note that while the seats were on Russian flights, Space Adventures is a privately held company with commercial interests.

Comment: Sure, but - again, not what was asked. In addition that was barely tourism - but I know what you mean. I'll update the question to clarify a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

11 years after this question was asked, and 10 years after the accepted answer's optimistic announcement that Virgin Galactic will start regular flights in 2013, **it's happening**!  Kinda:

Virgin's flight [Galactic 02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_02) took place in August 2023, with [paying civilian passengers on board for the first time](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2023/aug/10/vigin-galactic-space-flight-vss-unity-landing).  And they're promising roughly-monthly flights going forward, with Galactic 03 scheduled for September.

A couple of caveats:

- The flights max out at 88.5 km, which is space by some definitions but below the 100 km Karman line, and far too low/slow to (eg) ever dock with the ISS.
- Tickets cost a cool $450,000 as of 2022, so less than a million, but not exactly chump change.
- You only get about 4 minutes of weightlessness at the top of parabola.
- The multi-part vehicle design they're using is generally reckoned to be an evolutionary dead end *and* quite dangerous, they already had a [fatal crash in 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSS_Enterprise_crash).

So I'm still waiting for Elon to get [Starship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship) off the ground until I start booking my tickets to space.

Comment: There’s also Blue Origin’s program, which apparently has a cost of between $200K and $300K, but suffers similar limitations. Apparently you can also get to orbit for $50 to $100 million…

Comment: @jcaron Blue Origin hasn't flown since they had a booster failure in Sep 2022.

Comment: All you get is 4 min of zero g? You can get I think around 90 seconds of zero g with a parabola flight and then you get that multiple times in a trip.